# Right Click on ListView WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, visual-c++

I have a window with a listview which I would like to right click an entry in the listview and have certain options displayed in a context menu. I cant find any examples for C++. The similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001398/how-to-create-a-context-menu-on-listbox-right-click) but this is for listbox and i cant make it work in my program

So far I could not find any examples for c++ online. I could make it work for WM_LBUTTONDOWN on my main window but not on listview. Anyway, this is my code which i cant make it work:

```
case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
        if ((HWND)wParam == hWndListView) {
            POINT cursor;
            GetCursorPos(&cursor);
            TrackPopupMenu((HMENU)GetSubMenu(LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_CONTEXT)), 0), TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, cursor.x, cursor.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
        }
        break;
```

Any advise? Thanks

Answer:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    // When right button clicked on mouse
    if ((((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom) == hWndListView)
    {
        switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
        {
        case NM_RCLICK:
        {
            POINT cursor; // Getting the cursor position
            GetCursorPos(&cursor);
            // Creating the po-up menu list
            TrackPopupMenu((HMENU)GetSubMenu(LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_CONTEXT)), 0), TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, cursor.x, cursor.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
        }
            break;
        }
            break;
    }
    break;
```

This works under WndProc

Comment: Clarification: So the code gets called but no menu appears? Or the code does not get called? or....

Comment: The code does not get called at all.

Comment: any idea how to make use of [this][http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774873(v=vs.85).aspx]?

Comment: `NM_RCLICK` is sent to the ListView's parent window as a [`WM_NOTIFY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx) message. You have to catch it in the parent window's message procedure, not in the ListView's message procedure.

Comment: Hi Remy Lebeau, so how shall i change the code? im sorry, im very new to winapi programming